# Custom Post Type Archives by Date (stored as meta value) WP3.1

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, archives, date-time

I would like to implement date-based archive functionality (similar to original WP Archives widget functionality) for custom post type (CPT). What makes it difficult is the fact that I need to group and **archive events** not by published date, but **by `event_date` stored as a meta value**.

For example, I have `event` CPT registered as following:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'has_archive' => 'past-events',
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'event','with_front' => false),
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'menu_position' => 15,
    'supports' => array(
      'title',
      'editor',
      'author',
      'revisions'       
    )
  );
  register_post_type('event',$args);
```

I would like to generate archive links like `/past-events/2011/04`, similar to the functionality of WP Archives widget. However, my events should be archived by the `event_date` meta value. Also, if, say for April 2011, there are more events than my `Blog pages show at most` setting, I would like to have a correct pagination for pages. And ideally, when viewing a single event I would have correct previous and next event links within that archive page. Hope that makes sense.

I'm using WP3.1 I've gone as far as specifing `has_archive` setting for the CPT. I did look around, but got confused how to proceed. Is that something I have to write myself or it could be done with WP functions or plugins?

Would really appreciate any help and tips.

Many thanks,
Dasha

Comment: You can't achieve that with the build in functions nor do i know of any plugin that would help you do that and to write this kind of functionality would mean a lot of code.... but there might be a simpler solution, So in what format is your `event_date` meta value?

Comment: @Bainternet, it's stored as a string `"YYYY-MM-DD"`.

Comment: Ok so a suggested solution would be to modify the `post_date` field based on your 'event_date' meta value on `save_post` action hook, that way you could use all build in function in a regular manner.

Comment: @Bainternet will this affect when events appear on the site? What I means is when I create a future event, say 2 month ahead, I want it to show up on the site. I think if I change the `post_date` the event will be published on that date and won't be seen before that?

Comment: Not sure if that will happen, i just tried changing a post_date to 22-03-2012 and it showed up just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question fully but it's an attempt to help.

Take a look at: http://seebz.net/notes/#note-145 Sets up a CPT with date archives and sets up all the necessary rewrite rules.

As for using `wp_get_archives()` it doesn't have the necessary hooks of filters for it to work with a CPT so I recommend that you copy the function and alter to your liking.